# Moving an argument into a std::thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, thread-safety, c++14

Please consider the following code:

```
void h(M m2) 
{ 
    ...
}

int main()
{
  while (true) {
    M m1 = ...;
    std::thread t(h, std::move(m1));
    t.detach();
  }
}
```

Is it guaranteed that `m2` is properly `move`-d constructed from `m1` before `m1` is destroyed?  Or is there a race?

Comment: Why are those two related? Can't neither be the case?

Comment: Only copying stuff into the `thread` object happens before the thread starts: "The completion of the invocation of the constructor synchronizes with the beginning of the invocation of the copy of `f`." The further details of the thread execution are unrelated to the first thread.

Comment: A move is a shallow copy plus detaching the source from resources (data). Hence it is safe, if the move constructor/assignment is implemented properly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The standard seems clear to me:

> *Effects:* Constructs an object of type thread. The new thread of execution executes `INVOKE (DECAY_COPY ( std::forward<F>(f)), DECAY_COPY (std::forward<Args>(args))...)` with the calls to
>   `DECAY_COPY` being evaluated in the constructing thread.

Since the copy is made in the calling thread it must complete before the constructor invocation returns.

Construction of `m2` is done from a different object (the result of  the DECAY_COPY), not from `m1`, so it doesn't matter whether `m1` has been destroyed or not.

The result of the DECAY_COPY must be stored somewhere by the implementation so that it doesn't go out of scope until the target function has been initialized, but that is the implementation's job to get right. Destruction of `m1` doesn't have any effect on it.

Comment: Yeah, that's how I expected it to work.  Thanks Jonathan.